# Парсинг страницы расписания

Tags: qt, c++, синтаксический-анализ

Необходимо программно отправить запрос и получить расписание на нужную группу и дату. Как можно это реализовать? В какую сторону копать? Вот сайт http://www.sarfti.ru/?do=rasp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала надо посмотреть куда какие запросы отправляются. Через FireBug видно, что после нажатия на кнопку "Просмотр" к серверу делается post запрос с рядом параметром. Далее ты из qt с помощью инструментов фрейворка конструируешь эти запросы, данные для параметров (недели, группы и т.д.) можешь сливать с сайта и парсить. 
И посылаешь нужный запросы. В своей программе уже обрабатываешь результат так, как тебе хочется.

Это общая схема, точнее не скажу, т.к. с qt работал немного и то полгода назад, но там все делается очень просто.

Поискал и нашел интересную статью, которая поможет. Общий ход мыслей у нас совпал :)

http://wincode.org/cpp/cpp-html-dom-qt

Comment: Огромное спасибо)